# How to begin with Windows Kernel Programming?

Tags: kernel, windows-kernel

I am an application developer mostly work in C#. I have some knowledge of C/C++. I am very much fascinated and interested in windows Kernel Development. I Sketched out a layout to learn this.

```
1. Understand Windows internals(By books)
2. Try Simple Modules and keep expanding.
```

To achieve this, I need some help on:

```
1. The books I should read.
2. The Websites I should follow.
3. Setting up my dev environment.(Most important as I can start realizing.)
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Read [Windows Internals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901.aspx).

Read [Windows Drivers Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Follow and read [OSR Online](https://community.osr.com/categories/ntdev).

To start writing read [Writing your first driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554811%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This should cover you for several years or more.

Comment: Add this book as well.Windows Kernel Programming
Book by Pavel Yosifovich

https://g.co/kgs/dupniw

Answer (score 0):

My learning curve is a little different than yours, but it leads to exactly the same direction. So, I'm also C# developer with basic knowledge about C/C++, but I started my journey with discovering what are internals of .NET - I'm not talking about how does compiler complies code, but about edge between managed code and win32 api.

I've read [Advanced .NET Debugging](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321578899) where I was able to become familiar with debuggers different than Visual Studio. Then I skipped to Windows Internals (as @SomeWittyUsername mentioned).