# Resource allocation functions available to use for user program to allocate resources like IO and internet adaptor on WIndows 10 kernel

Tags: c, operating-system, windows-10, kernel, intel

I am looking into WIndows 10 kernel. I like to know the main functions available or some information where I can search forward to start. I will be using C and would like some information which can be useful for me to start this researching. Basically I like to know resource allocation user functions or ways of kernel which I can try searching more. Please be specific. resource allocation ways or functions like internet adaptor (just an example). and provide terminologies. My system is 64bit machine windows 10 intel. provide details which I would use to test using C language.

Thank you,
I will be open for more informaion to provide on question, what u like me to ask, just comment (please try not to close down question). just add a comment and I will see. I will appreciate if u be specific in comment

Comment: Please see the accepted answer for [How to begin with Windows Kernel Programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19634253/4142924)

Comment: And the Windows kernel [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/windows-kernel-mode-kernel-library).

Comment: ??? You do not allocate IO and you do not allocate internet adapters